# Randomize PCB trace generation with Altium Designer

Tags: pcb-design, altium, security, random

We are trying to create a tamper mesh as a flex PCB. This tamper mesh will consist of around 10 signal traces in order to detect a tamper.
One crucial point is that this tamper mesh should be different each time we generate it. This way it makes it harder to probe the protected circuitry without tamper detection.

Altium has its autoroute, there is also the interactive length tuning tool.
Is there a tool to randomly fill out a PCB area with the given traces?

Something like this but without dead ends.
The traces have a start point and an endpoint each with its own pad to connect to an MCU.

[image]

Comment: Assuming you make several PCBs from each artwork, you will have many boards with the same mesh. How about having a consistent mesh on the artwork, and fuse-programming it on a per-board level, so it's truly different with every physical board? It might need some thought about how to access the fuses (narrow necks in the track), but I'm sure it could be done.

Comment: Seems like a manufacturing nightmare. I think you would be better off just hand making x different ones. x could be how many of these fit on a single sheet of FR4.